# Combine the use of velocity.js' slideUp and begin: function

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

How do you combine these two, so that one can slide an item up, but trigger some JS just as that animation starts.

**SlideUp code**

```
 .velocity("slideUp", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });
```

**Begin: code**

```
$element.velocity({
    opacity: 0
}, { 
    /* Log all the animated divs. */
    begin: function(elements) { console.log(elements); }
});
```

Doing something like this doesn't work.

```
.velocity("slideUp", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 }), { 
    /* Log all the animated divs. */
    begin: function(elements) { console.log(elements); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the`begin` property inside the options object:

```
.velocity("slideUp", {
    delay: 500, duration: 150,
    begin: function(elements) { console.log(elements); }
});
```